# Trigger one php my admin sql statement for all users

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create notification system that when data inserted into `posts` table then a copy of that data should also be inserted into `notifications` table.

Copy of that data which goes to `notifications` should be only consist of `PostId`, and the rows which will be created will be for all users. I mean that a copy of that copy should be inserted for all users on different rows in `notifications` table. For example i have `576 users`, therefore 576 row of that copy should be made. I performed this task really awesome with `php` like beneath, but now i want to learn how to do it with `trigger`.

```
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$ReceiverIds = 'Select UserId from profiles';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$ReceiverIds);
//echo $result;
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $storeArray[] =  $row['UserId'];   
}
$values = "";
foreach($storeArray as $receiver){
    $values .= "('$receiver', 'New CEO Talk: $Title'
    ),\n";
}
$values = rtrim($values, ",\n");
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO notifications (
        `UserId`, `Title`
    )
    VALUES
    $values";
```

P.S. In php i used Title, but in trigger i want to use PostId instead of title.

So, I am asking that is there a way to perform above operation with `trigger`.

Comment: mysql <> sql server. I am guessing that you are using mysql from the code. And yes this can be done in a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Sean, can you provide me a way to do it.

Comment: @Rameen:  see the mysql documentation for triggers, you want an "after insert" trigger on the posts table.

Comment: I know the after in trigger but I stack on how to use that trigger for all users. I know for one but instead I want to make that trigger to create copy for all users from users table.